# How to increase font-size in report? (Without HTML Viewer)

Tags: abap

I wrote a report, which shows a `selection-screen comment`.
Now I am trying to increase the `font-size` of this text.

Do you have any hints how the text could be shown larger?

```
SELECTION-SCREEN COMMENT 20(55) text-007.
```

[image: selection-screen of the report]

Comment: Font size is configured in SAP-GUI and not inside the report.

Comment: Please don't post code as image, as per StackOverflow rules. I did the correction.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change font for SAP Dynpro objects. Alternatively you can do this for html header in ALV report.

Answer (score 0):

> SELECTION-SCREEN COMMENT 20(55) text-007.

No, In Abap you can not change the font on dynpros.

`selection-screen` commands are used to generate dynpros.
Dynpros are very fixed in nature.

The fonts used on sap gui dynpros are managed by sap gui and require a new sap logon session to take affect.

It is however possible to Highlight the field.  Perhaps a useful compromise.

```
REPORT ZTESTREP.
SELECTION-SCREEN COMMENT 20(55) text-006.
SELECTION-SCREEN SKIP 1.
SELECTION-SCREEN COMMENT 20(55) text-007.
PARAMETERS: TEST as CHECKBOX.
INITIALIZATION.
at SELECTION-SCREEN  OUTPUT.
loop at screen.
   if screen-name cs '007'.
       screen-intensified = '1'.
   endif.
   MODIFY SCREEN.
ENDLOOP.
```

[image]